# Karate - match response for greater or less than

Tags: karate

For my Karate Tests, I do have certain scenarios where I need to compare integer results for Greater or Less than equal to . As of now, for the `match` operation, there is just `'==' or '!='`.

Is there a way I can validate 'Greater than equal to ' or 'Less than' type of operators ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are multiple ways:

```
* def foo = 5
* assert foo <= 6

* def bar = { a: 1 }
* match bar == { a: '#? _ > 0' }
```

Refer: 
[`assert`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#assert) | ['self' expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions)

Comment: Does this work for arrays? I.e if I have two arrays with unix epoch times, can I compare them both for whichever one occurs earlier?
`Array1 {Dates: 100, 200, 300, timezone: est}
Array2 {Dates: 90, 190, 290, timezone: est}
* match each Array1 == {Dates: '#? _ >= Array2}`

Comment: @hungryhippos take some time to read the other question I linked. if needed, ask a new question and be clear please with good, simple examples etc